# Error with "message": "Forbidden" trying to query an Apollo Serverless Lambda server

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, serverless

I'm trying to following this example, https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/, to create a serverless GraphQL server which returns 'Hello world'.

The root directory contains essentially just two files, `graphql.js` and `serverless.yml`:

```
> tree . -I node_modules
.
├── graphql.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── serverless.yml
```

where, as in the example, `graphql.js` reads

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-lambda');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello world!',
  },
}

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler();
```

and `serverless.yml` reads

```
service: apollo-lambda

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: graphql.graphqlHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: post
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: get
          cors: true
```

This seems to deploy successfully:

```
> serverless deploy
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
.....
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service apollo-lambda.zip file to S3 (4.55 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
....................................
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Service Information
service: apollo-lambda
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: apollo-lambda-dev
resources: 12
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  POST - https://e9g6evoks0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql
  GET - https://e9g6evoks0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql
functions:
  graphql: apollo-lambda-dev-graphql
layers:
  None
Serverless: Run the "serverless" command to setup monitoring, troubleshooting and testing.
```

However, if I go to the playground and query 'hello', I get a 'forbidden' message:

[image]

That is, my

```
query {
  hello
}
```

rather than resulting in the response documented at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/server/, results in a

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Forbidden"
  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, i found the error. There is a known issue with apollo-server-lamdba.

While browsing the playground (at https://e9g6evoks0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql), the url of the endpoint is prefiled but it misses the `/dev/` part (the stage part defined in serverless.yml). Just add it and this will work fine.

cfr: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2136#issuecomment-458465128

Comment: I'm still missing something. what did you do to fix this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue even after adding stage dev. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the original tutorial already has the solution ([Setting up GraphQL Playground](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/lambda/#setting-up-graphql-playground)). Just edit your code as below.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    typeDefs, 
    resolvers, 
    playground: {
        endpoint: "/dev/graphql"
    }
});
```